# What is my web app coded in?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, architecture

I originally planned to build my web app in a MVC pattern, i was just wondering if it meets that?

I currently have this

Index page ------(Ajax Requests)---> Controllers ------> model

The data however seems to go from the model back to the controller and then passed back to the index page via ajax. I also use a bean for user login details..

What sort of architecture is this? Is it MVC, (there is no view?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the point of view.

From the client side point of view:

- Model: the webservice.
- Controller: the JS/Ajax code.
- View: the HTML DOM tree.

From the server side webservice point of view:

- Model: the business code.
- Controller: whatever servlet you used to control the request/response.
- View: the JSP page.

From the server side business point of view:

- Model: database entities.
- Controller: business domain objects.
- View: the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Well... you index page is the view, so it qualifies as "MVC".

But bear in mind that "MVC" is a pattern for the presentation tier, and the "Model" is not only the Database but all the business logic associated with it. There is a common misconception that View=Presentation Tier, Controller=Business Logic tier and Model=Database tier. Check out [the J2EE blueprints](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/MVC-detailed.html) and the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) about it.